# document.getElementById() is not defined when running browser code in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I was trying to use the `document.getElementbyId()` but when I run the console it tells me it is not defined.

My index.html and index.js are in the same folder the source should be OK.

I'm using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in Visual Studio Code and then choose "Run: without debbuging". The error message shows in the integrated console.

```js
let word1 = "Alex";
let word2 = "Toko";




 let example = `${word1} ${word2}`;

 var doc = document.getElementById("test").innerText = example;
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   

</head>
<body>
    <p id="test"> </p>
    
    <script src="index.js"> </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where and how are you running this? The example you have here doesn't recreate the problem.

Comment: Hi, i'm using Vs code and when i use " cmd + shift + P"  and use "Run: without debbuging" the console tells me that "document is not defined".

Comment: Try opening the page in a browser instead. It seems that VS Code is trying to execute the JavaScript by itself, separate from the HTML file.

Comment: Test your code in the browser.

Comment: Oh, ok it actually works on the browser, thank you ! Is there a way to fix the problem on vs code and make it works on its console ?

Comment: You could use the extension [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the waqy you're running the code.

cmd+shift+P will run the index.js on it's own, and it won't know or care about the html.

Instead, open the html in your browser, and it should work.

The reason it won't work on vs code is that it runs the javascript file directly, and while the html links to the javascript, it won't work the other way around.

cmd+shift+P is used for server-side javascript, not client side. client side, you can just test in browser.

Comment: Ok got it, it was actually working on my browser. Thank you for your answer